# Weird buffering mechanism with System.out.println()

Tags: java, spring, io, jvm, buffer

```
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    System.out.println("This works");
    throw new RuntimeException();
```

Console output:

```
Exception in thread "main" This works
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at com.ved.Myapp.App.main(App.java:16)
```

What is that weird output on the console?

I read somewhere that system.out.println() flushes the output buffer everytime because of the '\n' character. But something strange is going in the above code.

I also tried flushing the output buffer explicity, still same output.

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
System.out.println("This works");
throw new RuntimeException();
```

Console output:

```
Exception in thread "main" This works
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at com.ved.Myapp.App.main(App.java:16)
```

Is the Application context creation affecting the code below it? Because the moment I remove the Application context line, everything works fine and the output is as intended.

Comment: @user85421, Ok I will keep in mind that image related thing, I wasn't aware of that.
Also, thanks for the answer. I didn't have any idea that the two streams are independent. But still, I would like to ask that despite they are independent, one of them should be logged completely to the screen before the another. Why is it that half of the ouput of System.err is getting logged and then System.out and then remaining output of System.err ?

Comment: "keep in mind"-> better, please edit the question to at least also include the source as `formatted` text (the images as additional information are fine, in this special case even helpful) -- probably each stream is being handled by a different thread, eventually with different priorities

Comment: Ok, will check about it. Thanks

Comment: 'flush the buffer' does not necessarily mean that the characters have made it all the way to the destination, it just means that the buffer contents have been handed over to the OS.